# C# Not able to get the current select record value from my navigation

Tags: c#, sql

Hey i am getting a error telling me "Column 'RowNumber' does not belong to table Table1". the navigation works fine when i comment out the currentRecord line but i am no longer getting the value of current selected record. BandMember is the table managing the many to many relationship of band and member.

Here my method:

private void LoadBandMembers()
        {

```
        string sqlMemberID = $"SELECT * FROM BandMember WHERE BandID = {currentBandID} AND MemberID = {currentMemberID}";
        string sqlNav = 
            $@"
                SELECT 
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BandMember) AS NumberOfBandMember,
                (SELECT TOP(1) BandID as FirstBandID FROM BandMember
                ) as FirstBandID,
                (
                    SELECT TOP(1) MemberID as FirstMemberID FROM BandMember
                ) as FirstMemberID,
                q.PreviousBandID,
                q.PreviousMemberID,
                q.NextBandID,
                q.NextMemberID,
                (
                    SELECT TOP(1) BandID as LastBandID FROM BandMember ORDER BY BandID Desc
                ) as LastBandID,
                (
                    SELECT TOP(1) MemberID as LastMemberID FROM BandMember ORDER BY BandID Desc
                ) as LastMemberID
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT BandID, MemberID,
                    LEAD(BandID) OVER(ORDER BY BandID) AS NextBandID,
                    LEAD(MemberID) OVER(ORDER BY BandID) AS NextMemberID,  
                    LAG(BandID) OVER(ORDER BY BandID) AS PreviousBandID,
                    LAG(MemberID) OVER(ORDER BY BandID) AS PreviousMemberID,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BandID) AS 'RowNumber'
                    FROM BandMember
                ) AS q
                WHERE q.BandID = {currentBandID} AND q.MemberID = {currentMemberID}
                ORDER BY q.BandID, q.MemberID
                ";


        sqlNav = DataAccess.SQLCleaner(sqlNav);

        string[] sqlStatements = new string[] { sqlMemberID, sqlNav };

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = DataAccess.GetData(sqlStatements);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            DataRow selectedBandMember = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            int bandID = Convert.ToInt32(selectedBandMember["BandID"]);
            int memberID = Convert.ToInt32(selectedBandMember["memberID"]);

            cmbBand.SelectedValue = selectedBandMember["BandID"];
            cmbMember.SelectedValue = selectedBandMember["MemberID"];

            numberOfBandMember = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["NumberOfBandMember"]);
            firstBandID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["FirstBandID"]);
            firstMemberID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["FirstMemberID"]);
            previousBandID = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["PreviousBandID"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables["Table1"].Rows[0]["PreviousBandID"]) : (int?)null;
            previousMemberID = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["PreviousMemberID"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables["Table1"].Rows[0]["PreviousMemberID"]) : (int?)null; ;
            nextBandID = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["NextBandID"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables["Table1"].Rows[0]["NextBandID"]) : (int?)null;
            nextMemberID = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["NextMemberID"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables["Table1"].Rows[0]["NextMemberID"]) : (int?)null; ;
            lastBandID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["LastBandID"]);
            lastMemberID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["LastMemberID"]);
            currentRecord = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["RowNumber"]);


            DisplayToolStrip();
        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("The band member no longer exists");
            LoadFirstBandMembers();
        }


    }
```